# Specify address at runtime for generated workflow activities

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a service that runs WF4 workflows using WorkflowApplication. These workflows make use of generated activities from WCF soap services. I'm looking for a way of specifying the endpoint address at runtime, for each workflow run, of the different soap services. Any idea how this is possible while still being able to use the generated activities?

**Notes**

- Currently the consumed soap services have their bindings declared in
  the local app.config file.
- This post on MSDN provides an overview on how to generate the services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg281653.aspx